# Microstrip blocking capacitor ground cutout -- large cutout size

Tags: microstrip, compensation

I'm attempting to minimize the \$S_{11}\$ of a \$10\,\text{pF}\$ DC blocking capacitor on a microstrip trace for my signal frequency range, which is \$5.3-5.9\,\text{GHz}\$. My microstrip trace width is \$0.38\,\text{mm}\$.

I started by using a 0402 cap (\$0.5\,\text{mm}\$ width), but the performance was poor (results below). I'm using [OpenEMS](https://openems.de/start/) to simulate the behavior. Using a 0201 cap (\$0.3\,\text{mm}\$ width) improved the performance significantly, but still yielded worse performance than I would like.

To improve the performance further, I used a ground cutout below the capacitor. Since I didn't know the size to use, I let [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) choose a cutout width that minimized \$S_{11}\$ in my frequency range. I chose the length of the cutout to be the full extent of the capacitor+pads in all simulations. Interestingly, the optimizer came back with a really large cutout: almost \$4.5\,\text{mm}\$. Sure enough, though, this improved the performance dramatically in the signal frequency range at the expense of broadband performance. Here's a bird's eye view diagram showing the cutout, followed by a plot of the results.

[image]

[image]

*The Qucs line is a [Qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/) simulation that I've used as an ideal baseline to compare against the other simulations.*

Does this result seem reasonable? Previously, I'd thought cutouts were only used when the capacitor was wider than the signal trace, and in that case, the cutout would be much smaller than it is here.

---

**EDIT**

I'm using [Oshpark's 4-layer process](https://docs.oshpark.com/services/four-layer/), which has a dielectric of 3.64 (substrate is [FR408](https://docs.oshpark.com/resources/four-layer-substrate-FR408HR.pdf)), substrate height of \$0.1702\,\text{mm}\$ (I'm using the 1st and 2nd copper layer) and 1oz copper top layer and 0.5oz copper 2nd layer.

Comment: Can you share a diagram of your microstrip geometry (dielectric height, Dk, etc)?

Comment: I've added the dimensions in an edit to the original post. Would a diagram be helpful as well?

Comment: You've created an LC resonant filter. If you want to use this, consider that the capacitor value, dielectric height, dielectric constant, and copper width will vary due to manufacturing tolerances, and do some tolerance analysis before you choose a design.

Comment: Ok, I'll run some more simulations on that, but the tolerance issue makes me nervous since I think it could vary quite a bit (e.g. oshpark doesn't have impedance control). I guess I could just omit the cutout, or use a much smaller cutout which just seems to place the resonant point at a much higher frequency. However, I was surprised at how much worse the performance was in all cases than the ideal baseline. Is \$-15\,\text{dB}\$ reasonable performance for something like this?

Comment: You should not use cutouts along microstrip transmission line: cutouts interrupt return current. What is your simulated loss without any blocking cap?

Comment: I was seeing about \$-50\,\text{dB}\$ for \$S_{11}\$ without a blocking cap. However, it could be lower since I cut the simulation off once the energy dissipated by \$50\,\text{dB}\$. In any event, much better than with the blocking cap.

Comment: The red line is the 0201 cap without a cutout.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, At my company we use cutouts under components all the time to opimtize return loss. It reduces capacitance and increases inductance to compensate for the pad capacitance. This isn't some wild-ass idea nobody's ever done before.

Comment: @ThePhoton is there a return loss you'd aim for in a situation like this?

Comment: @MattHusz, it would depend on the system requirements. Also, we're doing digital work so usually we need a broadband match rather than just a notch at one operating frequency.

Comment: @ThePhoton, with 0.38 mm trace and 0201 cap (0.3 mm width), there is no pad to compensate for. The actual reflection is coming from a 4-fold jump in effective conductor thickness (the 0201 cap is 0.14 mm tall). I am not sure if the simulation tool accounts for the actual 3D cap parameters, with parasitic inductance, ESR, etc. I am afraid that reality might surprise the simulations...

Comment: @Ale..chenski it does not. Unfortunately OpenEMS does not support lumped inductances, otherwise I would have. I could have simulated the series resistance, but I figured the inductance was the more important factor so I didn't bother.

Comment: Where are you getting the 0.14mm height? Is that standard? I was seeing 0.3mm height when I looked. E.g. [this cap](https://search.murata.co.jp/Ceramy/image/img/A01X/G101/ENG/GJM0335C1E100JB01-01.pdf). The simulation does account for the height, just not the parasitics.

Comment: Matt, I am confused here. The MLCC has a complex electro-mechanical structure, and even a 10pF 0201 cap looks more like an inductor at 6 GHz. So I am not sure about accuracy of this kind of simulations...I was looking at Murata data, 0.3 is even worse.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at even smaller cap, https://www.murata.com/en-global/products/productdetail?partno=GRM0115C1E100JE01%23&excid=ww_pa-o_ow_ctl_c02e-22_2020

Comment: @Ale..chenski what's my best bet here given I don't have access to a commercial simulator? I can simulate the parasitics with Qucs and the "size parasitics" with OpenEMS, but not both together. GJM0335C1H100GB01 murata cap has SRF just below 4GHz and total impedance around \$5\,\Omega\$ at 6GHz. That's about the best I could find without using a smaller cap which I don't think I'd be able to hand solder. I do have access to a VNA that I could test prototypes with.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, Are you sure that the parasitics in the Murata model don't include effects from some particular mounting geometry?

Comment: @ThePhoton, no, I am not sure of anything...

Comment: I found [a document](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing_data/pdf/en-us/mlcc/sim_mlcc_measuringcond_e_201908.pdf) detailing the measurement procedure. They apparently correct for the mounting geometry, so the data should be for the capacitor alone.

Comment: Given this, it seems the best course of action would be to use the s-parameter data provided by murata, add a shunt capacitor and series inductor to simulate the capacitance/inductance due to the narrower or wider trace ([wcalc](http://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/microstrip.cgi) can perform that calculation) and then compensate accordingly (e.g. a ground cutout for a 0402 cap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this result seem reasonable?

It is reasonable as a simulation result.

By cutting out the ground plane, you force the return currents to flow further from the signal currents. This increases the inductance of the structure. With sufficient inductance and the lumped capacitor you form an LC circuit that at some frequency looks like a short between one section of transmission line and the the other. Using your optimization procedure you adjusted the geometry to make this frequency equal to your operating frequency.

Practically, it might not be a good idea to try to use this effect to match your line because

- The resonant frequency will be affected by manufacturing variation of the dielectric thickness, dielectric constant, copper thickness, capacitor value, etc.
- There is some uncertainty about the capacitor model. You haven't said what model you use (lumped capacitance, RLC equivalent circuit, 2-port s-parameters, ...) but very likely the model provided by the manufacturer includes some effect from the test fixture they mounted it in during characterization. How to back-out those fixture effects to predict the behavior in your circuit geometry is a tricky question.

As mentioned by Ale..chenski in comments, we more often use ground plane cut-outs for pad matching when the pad width is greater than the transmission line width we're trying to match.

Comment: Are there any compensation techniques for when the capacitor width is less than the microstrip width? I'm debating whether to use a 0201 or 0402 cap for my test prototypes. I'm tempted to go with the 0201 which will have lower inductance and gives a better baseline simulation result (simulation uses a lumped capacitance model and ignores parasitics like ESL and ESR).

Comment: I can, of course, prototype both but I'd like to keep costs down, especially if I need to try several different cutouts for the 0402.

Comment: To attempt to answer my own question, I expect the way to compensate for a small cap would be to bring the coplanar ground plane closer. However, like the rest of this I expect this would be difficult to achieve repeatable results given the manufacturer tolerances.